# Arrangement of houses with 2 colors

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

From the 2016 International Mathematical and Logic Games Contest

> Along the coast of Maths-land, the straight beach-front
>   road contains a line of houses, all on the same side of the
>   road. The houses are painted either blue or yellow and
>   there is at least one house of each colour. Curiously
>   enough, every pair of houses separated by ten other
>   houses is painted the same colour, as is every pair
>   separated by fifteen houses.
>   What is the maximum number of houses on this road?

Bruteforcing this with a computer I found that $25$ is the maximum. I've been looking for a formal proof, to no avail. My combinatoric skills are very limited, perhaps someone can come up with a short proof...

Comment: Clarification on what is meant by, "*..every pair of houses separated by ten other houses is painted the same colour...*". Suppose you have the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ house and the $j^{\mathrm{th}}$ house. Does this mean that if $|i-j|=10$ then these houses are the same colour, or that there are literally $10$ houses between the $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ and $j^{\mathrm{th}}$ house, so $|i-j|-1=10$ means they are the same colour? I think it must be the latter of these two, because otherwise I don't think there is a limit on the number of houses.

Comment: @MikePierce It's the latter.

Comment: I think that cranking it out about like Barry Cipra did might be the intended way to do it for the contest since it really doesn't take that long (you can build it from the bottom up to see that $25$ is the maximum). If there is a slicker way to do this problem, it would probably have to use the fact that since $11$ and $16$ are relatively prime, any positive integer can be written as $11n + 16m$ for suitable $n$ and $m$. Then for each house, talk about what $m$ and $n$ must be.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to show that $25$ is the maximum would be to observe that the chain

$$11\to22\to6\to17\to1\to12\to23\to7\to18\to2\to13\to24\to8\to19\to3\to14\to25\to9\to20\to4\to15\to26\to10\to21\to5\to16$$

where each step in the chain either goes up $11$ or down $16$, accounts for all the numbers from $1$ to $26$.  This shows that in any stretch of $26$ houses, all houses have the same color as the $11$th house.

Comment: I think that this pretty much takes care of it (especially since this wouldn't be too hard to crank out during a contest). The only things left to be shown is that there is a valid coloring on $25$ houses, and to argue that if there is a valid coloring on $25$ houses then there is a valid coloring on any fewer number of houses.

Comment: @MikePierce For $25$ (or fewer) houses, color $10,21,5,16$ blue and the rest yellow.